# Not able scroll down the page using selenium - nUnit, C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I am getting the following error while trying to click on a button which is present at the bottom of the page. Looks like this error is coming because that button is not visible at the first point, if we scroll the page down then only selenium is able to identify that button.

```
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException : element click intercepted: Element <span>...</span> is not clickable at point (1113, 659)..
```

I have tried with following code to scroll down the web page but it does not help me.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown);
```

If I try with `element.Sendkeys(Keys.ArrowDown)` then also its not helping.

what would be the correct approach here?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Actions` class to perform scrolling to the element in this way

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
var element = driver.FindElement(...);
actions.MoveToElement(element);
actions.Perform();
```

substitute `...` with the selector for the element.

There is also another method relying on javascript

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor) driver;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```